# How do I apply melt / wide_to_long onto a data frame with multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-melt

I have a one-hot encoded data frame that is similar to the one below:

| review_score | Action & Adventure | Classic Movies | TV Comedies | TV Mysteries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

it contains 40+ columns and I do not think it would be feasible to put every column name into the functions.

How can I pivot or rearrange the table so it looks something like the one below:

| Genre | review_score |
| --- | --- |
| Action & Adventure | 10 |
| Action & Adventure | 5 |
| Classic Movies | 7 |
| TV Comedies | 4 |
| TV Comedies | 8 |
| TV Mysteries | 7 |

I want each genre to have a row for each review score given in order to plot a boxplot

I have tried melt and wide_to_long functions but cannot get the desired data frame. Please advice!

Comment: Try `pd.from_dummies`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html

Answer (score 2):

In pandas 1.5.0+ there is [`pd.from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html)

```
import pandas as pd

genre = pd.from_dummies(df.drop(columns="review_score"))
pd.concat([genre[""].rename("Genre"), df["review_score"]], axis=1)
```

alternatively, use [`pd.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
genre = df.drop(columns="review_score").idxmax(axis=1)
pd.concat([genre.rename("Genre"), df["review_score"]], axis=1)
```

Comment: or `pd.from_dummies(df.set_index('review_score'))` or `pd.from_dummies(df.drop('review_score', axis=1))`

Comment: I agree that's a lot better with 40 columns ;). Thanks a lot @SomeDude, updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have 1.5.0+ version of pandas, you could do:

```
cols = ['review_score','Genre']
s = df.set_index('review_score').stack()
out = s[s==1].rename_axis(cols).reset_index()[cols]

print(out)

   review_score               Genre
0             4         TV Comedies
1            10  Action & Adventure
2             5  Action & Adventure
3             7      Classic Movies
4             8         TV Comedies
5             7        TV Mysteries
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iloc` and `idxmax(axis=1)` to find `column_name` then use [`pandas.Series.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add new column to old dataframe.

```
new_df = df['review_score'].to_frame().assign(Genre = df.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax(axis=1))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   review_score               Genre
0             4         TV Comedies
1            10  Action & Adventure
2             5  Action & Adventure
3             7      Classic Movies
4             8         TV Comedies
5             7        TV Mysteries
```

Answer (score 0):

hello i hope that help you, i work it with for loop

```
l=[]
k=[]
for i in df.columns[1:]:
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if df[i][j]==1:
            l.append(df.review_score[j])
            k.append(i)
result= pd.DataFrame()
result['Genre']=k
result['review_score']=l
```

Out put :

```
              Genre  review_score
0  Action_Adventure            10
1  Action_Adventure             5
2     ClassicMovies             7
3        TVComedies             4
4        TVComedies             8
5       TVMysteries             7
```